# WhatsApp QR API Calls

Tags: api, security, whatsapp

Wondering if anyone can help me. I'm interested to know the calls from the android phone when the QR is scanned (from the web whatsapp). Does anyone have any of the json data that's sent (obviously hide characters as it may be sensitive). I'm seeing if there is a way to get around it on my iPhone.